# IE8 Javascript Error

Tags: javascript

I have written a js method which runs perfectly on FF.
This js method is called on the click of a radio button.

In IE, when I click the radio button, the js method is called only when I click somewhere on the form. I have no idea about this strange behavious in IE.

Any ideas?

Thx

---

Here is my code.

```
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
```

HTML CODE:

```
<h:selectOneRadio  id="pid" value="#{Bean.pid}" onchange="javascript:checkPid();">    
<f:selectItem itemLabel="label1" itemValue="value1"/> 
<f:selectItem itemLabel="label2" itemValue="value2" /> 
<f:selectItem itemLabel="label3" itemValue="value3" /> 
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function checkPid() {
   //some basic js here
   //even if I just give an one-liner alert stmt here, In IE it 
   //shows up only when I click somewhere on the form after I click 
   //on the radio button
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you talking about the change event for radios? In FF, a radio's value is changed right after you click it. But it seems that in IE, the value is considered "changed" after it's clicked & loses focus.

Comment: Can you post some code. Include your HTML and JavaScript, otherwise its virtually impossible to help.

Comment: Why support Internet Explorer? IE support is a vicious cycle that can only be stopped by the *developer* first. If we continue its support, users will have no incentive to change browsers, and this will go on forever, or at least until Microsoft releases a decent browser (IE9, a complete rewrite, is actually quite nice). For now, however, the 55% of internet users using IE will have to face a slightly-harsh truth, and move on.

Comment: the "HTML" you posted is not html.  It's jsf markup.  Please "view source" in your browser to see what HTML is actually being generated by this markup.

Answer (score 1):

Try the onclick event rather than the onchange event.

You'll need to modify your code though:

```
<h:selectOneRadio  id="pid" value="#{Bean.pid}" onclick="checkPid(this);">
```

And your javascript function:

```
function checkPid(e) {
   //do stuff with e.value
}
```

You should be able to validate what the user clicked on by e.value.  This should work for both browsers.